# How to read draft message address , it always returns null value

Tags: android

I am implementing sms application, I want to store all sms values into internal xml file and restore sms values from xml file into sms application, so far inbox messages and sent messages working fine but problem with draft messages.
please help me on this , thank you.

Comment: Can you share your code and where you are getting the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create Draft box URI
Uri draftURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/draft");

// List required columns
String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

// Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content Provider
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// Fetch Sent SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
Cursor c = cr.query(draftURI, reqCols, null, null, null);



<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

[tutorial link](http://pulse7.net/android/read-sms-message-inbox-sent-draft-android/)

Comment: Thanks, but I have used the above code, I got the same result(null) of the draft message address

Comment: Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), null, null, null, "date asc"); 
    if(cursor!=null&&cursor.getCount()>0)
     {

     cursor.moveToFirst();
      do {
       sPhNumber  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
       Log.d("TAG", "SMSBackUpMoveFirst"+sPhNumber);

      } while(cursor.moveToNext());
}